# ASP.NET Web Api controller for stored procedure not returning data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have the following stored procedure on my database:

```
SELECT dbo.Persona.Nombre, dbo.Persona.Cedula, dbo.Prestamo.Empresa, dbo.Prestamo.Concepto, dbo.Prestamo.Monto, dbo.Prestamo.Fecha, dbo.Prestamo.PagadoATiempo
FROM dbo.Financiera INNER JOIN
     dbo.Prestamo ON dbo.Financiera.RNC = dbo.Prestamo.Empresa INNER JOIN
     dbo.Persona ON dbo.Prestamo.Cliente = dbo.Persona.Cedula
WHERE dbo.Persona.Cedula = @p1
```

which is then in my context class as:

```
 public partial class BDWSEntities : DbContext
{
    public BDWSEntities()
        : base("name=BDWSEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Financiera> Financieras { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Persona> Personas { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Prestamo> Prestamoes { get; set; }

    public virtual ObjectResult<EnviarHistorial_Result> EnviarHistorial(string p1)
    {
        var p1Parameter = p1 != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("p1", p1) :
            new ObjectParameter("p1", typeof(string));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<EnviarHistorial_Result>("EnviarHistorial", p1Parameter);
    }

    public virtual ObjectResult<Nullable<bool>> EnviarSalud(string p1)
    {
        var p1Parameter = p1 != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("p1", p1) :
            new ObjectParameter("p1", typeof(string));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Nullable<bool>>("EnviarSalud", p1Parameter);
    }
}
```

and I'm using the following controller to access it:

```
namespace Web_Services.Controllers
{
    public class HistorialController : ApiController
    {
        private BDWSEntities db = new BDWSEntities();
        public IHttpActionResult GetHistorial(string Cedula)
        {

            var record = db.EnviarHistorial(Cedula);
            if (record == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(record);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, in theory, this controller should return data, but when accessed via the relevant localhost/api/Historial, it doesn't return any data or message, it just returns an empty JSON file. What's happening?

Comment: "I have the following stored procedure" where? I don't see it in the question. You posted the same query twice

Comment: "then in my context class" that code isn't code of context. It is a query!

Comment: Oops, I done screwed it up. Fixed!

Comment: Do you understand what means "stored procedure"?

Comment: Yeah,  I accidentally pasted the stored procedure twice. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    public virtual ObjectResult<EnviarHistorial_Result> EnviarHistorial(string p1)
    {
        var p1Parameter = p1 != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("p1", p1) :
            new ObjectParameter("p1", typeof(string));

        return this.Database.SqlQuery<EnviarHistorial_Result>("EnviarHistorial", p1);
    }
```